# How to format multiple 'paragraphs' with the same indent settings in Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2011

I'm not sure if this has come about as a result of pasting from a Windows generated Word doc into a Mac one but some of the paragraph formatting is now slightly off.

Is there a way to select blocks of text and force it to all have the same indent settings?

the text is repeating blocks like

> THIS IS A HEADER
>
> - [**x**]bullet point with some stuff
> - another one
> - same again
>
> THIS IS ANOTHER HEADER
>
> - [**y**]more bullets
> - and again
> - and so on

Since pasting, [x] bullets and [y] bullets no longer line up vertically

Comment: why not using paste format button?

Comment: because that only appears to copy font style and colour

Comment: The button does copy the paragraph properties; you need to highlight the source paragraph totally (triple-click on it). It won't work if you highlight few words of it.

Comment: you have to totally select the source paragraph AND totally select the destination paragraph, failure to do it on both parts results in only partial formatting

Comment: I gather you managed to solve your problem?